# React - Re render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, spotify

Im building a simple spotify app using react for the first time. Currenty I am able to render the current track being played by a user with it automatically appearing on the page. If I change tracks quickly(within a few seconds) it renders the new track details on to the page. However if I wait a couple of seconds, it stops rendering. Any reason why?

below is an example of my code

```
    return (
    <div className="App">
      <a href='http://localhost:8888'>
      <button>Login But With Spotify</button>
      </a>
      {this.getNowPlaying()}
      <div> Now Playing: { this.state.nowPlaying.name} </div>
      <div> By: { this.state.nowPlaying.artist} </div>
      <div> Id: { this.state.nowPlaying.id} </div>
      <div>
        <img src={ this.state.nowPlaying.image} style={{ width: 100}}/>
      </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
```

Any help would be great :)

Comment: post more code please, the whole class would be great!

Comment: ive posted the entire class below - OP

Answer (score 0):

It is because you invoked the API call method "getNowPlaying" inside render method.

Each render cycle of react will call the render method, so it may be called many times.

Remove the `{this.getNowPlaying()}` from render and create a method "componentDidMount" and place it there. (see the code below)

The "componentDidMount" method is a react's component lifecycle method called after the component successfully mounted (initialized).

Read more in [react's class component lifecycle methods docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Spotify from 'spotify-web-api-js';
const spotifyWebApi = new Spotify();
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    const params = this.getHashParams();
    this.state ={
      loggedIn: params.access_token ? true : false,
      nowPlaying: {
        name: 'Not Checked',
        image: ''
       }
     }
    if (params.access_token){
      spotifyWebApi.setAccessToken(params.access_token)
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getNowPlaying()
  }
  getHashParams() {
    var hashParams = {};
    var e, r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g,
        q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    while ( e = r.exec(q)) {
       hashParams[e[1]] = decodeURIComponent(e[2]);
    }
    return hashParams;
  }
  getNowPlaying(){
    spotifyWebApi.getMyCurrentPlaybackState()
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          nowPlaying: {
            name: response.item.name,
            image: response.item.album.images[1].url,
            artist: response.item.artists[0].name,
            id: response.item.id
          }
        })
      }
    )
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div className="App">
      <a href='http://localhost:8888'>
      <button>Login But With Spotify</button>
      </a>
      <div> Now Playing: { this.state.nowPlaying.name} </div>
      <div> By: { this.state.nowPlaying.artist} </div>
      <div> Id: { this.state.nowPlaying.id} </div>
      <div>
        <img src={ this.state.nowPlaying.image} style={{ width: 100}}/>
      </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, Ive tried doing using the componentDidMount() function like mentioned above, however it now does not change at all when I switch to a new track in spotify..

Comment: In this case, you should look for a reactive API, websocket or something that enables you to register a listener to spotify track changes... Or you will need to implement a poll to update it regularly, like "this.interval = setInterval(() => this.getNowPlaying(), 5000)" (You will need to implement componentWillUnmount to clear that interval to prevent memory leak)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is some basic stuff.

Basically in your code, you get the new stuff on every rerender. Here there is the problem, the rerender happens only when a state, the parent or (not always) a prop changes. This can lead to some issues.

You see it working, because you change song before the `This.setState` is fired, so when setting the state, it triggers the component to rerender, which calls the function again. At this point, if the response has changed (basicly if you change the song), the state gets updated and this step is repeated, else, if the response is the same (didn't change the song in the meantime), the state doesn't change (leading the component not to rerender --> not refetching the data);

Here you can find the solution(s). One is class component, one is hooks (i've tested only the hooks' one). I personally would recommend the second one, because it's less code, more flexible and easier to understand!

I hope i could help you!

**Class Component**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Spotify from 'spotify-web-api-js';
const spotifyWebApi = new Spotify();
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    const params = this.getHashParams();
    this.state ={
      loggedIn: params.access_token ? true : false,
      nowPlaying: {
        name: 'Not Checked',
        image: ''
       }
     }
    if (params.access_token){
      spotifyWebApi.setAccessToken(params.access_token)
    }
  }
  getHashParams() {
    var hashParams = {};
    var e, r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g,
        q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    while ( e = r.exec(q)) {
       hashParams[e[1]] = decodeURIComponent(e[2]);
    }
    return hashParams;
  }
  componentDidMount(){
      this.getNowPlaying();
  }
  
  getNowPlaying(){
    spotifyWebApi.getMyCurrentPlaybackState()
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          nowPlaying: {
            name: response.item.name,
            image: response.item.album.images[1].url,
            artist: response.item.artists[0].name,
            id: response.item.id
          }
        })
        this.getNowPlaying();
      }
    )
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div className="App">
      <a href='http://localhost:8888'>
      <button>Login But With Spotify</button>
      </a>
      <div> Now Playing: { this.state.nowPlaying.name} </div>
      <div> By: { this.state.nowPlaying.artist} </div>
      <div> Id: { this.state.nowPlaying.id} </div>
      <div>
        <img src={ this.state.nowPlaying.image} style={{ width: 100}}/>
      </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Hooks**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Spotify from "spotify-web-api-js";
const spotifyWebApi = new Spotify();
function App() {
  //not used?
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState();
  //telling whether the component is mount or not
  const [isComponentMount,setIsComponentMount]=useState(true);
  //response container
  const [nowPlaying, setNowPlaying] = useState({
    name: "Not Checked",
    image: "",
    artist: "",
    id: ""
  });
  //Fetches the newest data
  const getNowPlaying = useCallback(() => {
    //Needed to stop the infinite loop after the component gets closed
    if(!isComponentMount)return;
    spotifyWebApi.getMyCurrentPlaybackState().then(response => {
      setNowPlaying({
        name: response.item.name,
        image: response.item.album.images[1].url,
        artist: response.item.artists[0].name,
        id: response.item.id
      });
      //Change this one as you like (perhaps a timeout?)
      getNowPlaying();
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    //Get hash params
    const params = {};
    var e,
      r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g,
      q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    while ((e = r.exec(q))) {
      params[e[1]] = decodeURIComponent(e[2]);
    }
    if (params.access_token) {
      spotifyWebApi.setAccessToken(params.access_token);
    }
    getNowPlaying();
    return ()=>{
      setIsComponentMount(false);
    }
  }, [getNowPlaying]);


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <a href="http://localhost:8888">
        <button>Login But With Spotify</button>
      </a>
      <div> Now Playing: {nowPlaying.name} </div>
      <div> By: {nowPlaying.artist} </div>
      <div> Id: {nowPlaying.id} </div>
      <div>
        <img src={nowPlaying.image} style={{ width: 100 }} alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App
```